# Adding multiple meta_key fields as orderby options to a WP Query via a function

Tags: wp-query, custom-field

I'm modifying an existing function that adds orderby options to a wp query. I need to add more than one meta_key as orderby fields. I have found and modified the following code, I just can't work out how to set the query to accept the array values within 'orderby' array.

I tried variations of `$query->set('orderby', array($orderby['orderby']));` but this broke the function

Any help is much appreciated! I am using Wordpress 4.9.1

```
function product_order_by($query)
{


    if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && is_archive('product')) {
        $orderby = [
            'meta_query' => [
                'relation' => 'AND',
                'query_one' => [
                    'key' => 'stock_listing_status'
                ],
                'query_two' => [
                    'key' => 'size'
                ] 
            ],
            'orderby' => [ 
                'query_one' => 'ASC',
                'query_two' => 'DESC',
                'menu_order' => 'DESC',
                'title' => 'ASC'

            ]
        ];                      
        $query->set('posts_per_page', 25);
        $query->set('orderby', $orderby); 

    } 

}
```

Comment: Is the function `product_order_by` a [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) callback?

Comment: Yes. Sorry forgot to mention

Comment: meta query parameters don't belong inside the orderby parameter.

Comment: @milo OK. How can I modify this function, i.e. sort by meta key THEN standard column name THEN meta key THEN standard name etc?